# Plugin development for KDE file manager

Tags: user-interface, kde-plasma, kdevelop, file-manager

I want to introduce a new field when right clicking on a file in Red Hat file browser. Assuming what I have read, the default file browser is Dolphin. But I am not sure how to go about developing a plugin/hack which could do the above.

Any links on tutorials or development pages which could specifically help me getting the task done will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you are looking for:

http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Creating_Konqueror_Service_Menus

generally, look on techbase.kde.org for infos around KDE development.